# Global convergence of ray cast against convex object

Tags: algorithm

In Gino Van Den Bergen's 2004 paper [Ray Casting against General Convex Objects with Application to Continuous Collision Detection](http://www.continuousphysics.com/ftp/pub/test/files/physics/papers/jgt04raycast.pdf), he first presents a naive iterative method to prep his discussion:

```
Algorithm 1 An iterative method for performing a ray cast of a ray s+λr against
a convex object C. For positive results, this algorithm terminates with λ being the
hit parameter, x, the hit spot, and n, the normal at x.

λ ← 0;
x ← s;
n ← 0;
c ← “the point of C closest to x”;
while not “x is close enough to c” do
begin
    n ← x − c;
    if n · r ≥ 0 then return false
    else
    begin
        λ ← λ − (n · n)/(n · r);
        x ← s + λr;
        c ← “the point of C closest to x”
    end
end;
return true
```

He then states:

> The property λi < λi+1 ≤ λhit is a necessary yet not sufficient
>   condition for global convergence. In order to show that, in case of a
>   hit, xi indeed approaches the hit spot for i → ∞, we need to show that
>   the mapping from λi to λi+1 is continuous at all λ<λhit.

However, for real numbers at least, the fact the sequence of λ's is monotonically increasing and bounded above is a sufficient condition for convergence. I am unsure why he needs to prove continuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a singularity at some point, it might be the case that λi+1 will asymptotically approach it, but will never be able to get past it. With limited-precision numbers it'll just mean that λ will stop increasing.

EDIT: ok I think I came up with an example of how a similar algorithm may fail to converge. Let's imagine our advancement strategy is a bit more cautious: once we find the closest point c, we advance λ halfway towards the point on the ray that's closest to c, i.e. λi+1 = λi - (n·r)/2, and additionally the object is not entirely convex but has a hole:
[image: AB=AC]

AB=AC, so there's a singularity at A. Our new algorithm will approach A, but will never reach it and be able to jump to C (since it only moves halfway each time), and yet λ will steadily increase at any point.

EDIT 2: Since A is a singularity point, n·r will actually get to 0 there, so I'm not sure if it ruins the argument:) Perhaps not if we define that exactly at A, C will be chosen as the closest point instead of B

Comment: Hmm, still foggy how we could even have singularities here given we have a monotonically increasing, bounded sequence for any initial 0 <= λ <= λhit. Can you help clarify by providing an example where this breaks?

Comment: for instance 1-e^-x is monotonically increasing, but it will never reach 2 (or even 1 for that matter)

Comment: This isn't a counter example though.

Comment: Can you provide some function f(x) that is bounded below by f(a) and above by f(b), where, upon taking any infinite, monotonically increasing sequence {x | a < x < b}, {f(x)} is monotonically increasing sequence, and yet f(x) has singularities inside a < x < b

Comment: the thing is that λi is bounded, but i itself isn't, and we are computing f(i) essentially, not f(λ). so if there's a singularity trap somewhere between 0 and λhit, i->i+1 stepping can get bogged down in it

Comment: Outside float space, we don't care i isn't bounded; in fact it can't be bounded if we want convergence. Potentially what he's doing there is, since the automorphism of {λ} is continuous over 0 < λhit, and since λhit is an upper bound for {λ}, λhit must be the least upper bound => lim{λ} = λhit.

Comment: Perhaps he should have written "The property λi < λi+1 ≤ λhit is a necessary yet not sufficient condition for global convergence **to λhit**.

Comment: i amended the answer with an example

Comment: Thank you for the response - great edit. I'm just thinking about this..not ignoring :)

Comment: Hey, sorry, been busy. After taking a little time to consider this, I'm not sure about the validity of the argument, but I think I understand where you're coming from nonetheless. Thanks for taking the time!